# `play dist`, the `main.css` returns 404

Tags: routes, assets, playframework-2.0

Create a new sample play2 app:

```
play new test
```

Then:

```
cd test
play run
```

Visit `http://localhost:9000`, we can see the default home page displayed correctly.

But when I dist it:

```
play dist
```

And upload the generated `dist/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip` to the server and unzip it, and run:

```
cd test-1.0.SNAPSHOT
./start
```

Then visit `http://myserver:9000`, I found the css file can't be found.

```
GET http://myserver:9000/assets/stylesheets/main.css
404
```

Since the app is built-in example provided by play2, doesn't mean it's a bug of play2?

PS:

The `routes` file:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /public path
GET     /assets/*file                       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

And the `Assets.scala` provided by play2 is:

```
object Assets extends Controller {

  def at(path: String, file: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action { request =>

    val resourceName = Option(path + "/" + file).map(name => 
        if (name.startsWith("/")) name else ("/" + name)).get

    if (new File(resourceName).isDirectory 
       || !new File(resourceName).getCanonicalPath.startsWith(new File(path).getCanonicalPath)) {
      NotFound
    } else {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Seems play is trying to find a dir and a file existing on the disk, but that `public` directory is packaged in `test-1.0-SANPSHOT/libs/test_2.9.1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, not a real file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find that CSS file even if you do "play run", so it's nothing to do with it being packaged in a jar.

Comment: "play run" works fine and the public asset for main.css is found. I haven't tried "dist" but "run" certainly works. ??

Comment: They said on the mailing list that Play will give you a 404 for any file that has no content in it even if the file is there, so that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solved for me : simply check that the file main.css is not empty.